# Which GNOME LINUX PHP IDE is most like phpDesigner in Windows?

Tags: php, linux, ide

I'm looking for a php editor can list all functions in one script and all variables in script, functions, classes. and count repeat of every variable. and auto-complete all default functions and user defined functions and variables and consts. and can search and replace in all files in one folder.

really I'm handy with phpDesigner and don't wanna use WinE!

Thanks for advance!

Comment: thanks Nanne! I've got my mistake. I didn't know what IDE means! And now trying 4 IDE, (Komodo, PDT, NetBeans, PHP Strom) and then tell you all that which is most like phpDesigner.

Comment: I Test all Komodo IDE, PDT, NetBeans, PHP Strom and I can say Komodo is the best exchange of phpDesigner. Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You looking for editor, and not IDE - so I'm not talking about Eclipse, Netbeans or PHPStrom (which is great BTW). But you should take a look at: [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit).

Comment: phpDesigner is php IDE too ;-) so please look at this link and tell me which Linux App is like [this](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php)? thanks a lot

Comment: So you want an IDE, not editor. Personally, I use PHPStorm (it's multiplatform). But ypu should look at the link posted below your question by @Aron.

Comment: @IVIR3zaM Komodo also has an IDE. As a PHPDesigner user like you, I can say it is almost perfect for me on linux, but it's not cheap.

Answer (score 2):

What about Eclipse PHP?

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Comment: +1 for Eclipse, its the best one I've ever used although don't install it via package manager!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org).

NetBeans supports all the features you need, like:

- Listing your functions
- Auto-Completion
- Searching and replacing in your files

and so on...

Comment: I,m Downloading NetBeans! and after try it answer you, thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

You can keep on using PHPDesigner 7 on linux with [wine](http://winehq.org/) with some tricks. I had installed and submitted my experiences on linux (ubuntu 10.10 back then) with PHPDesigner couple of months ago [here in Wine AppDB.](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21632)

Comment: wine in not stable and have low security.I was using phpDesigner on wine, but it hanging a lot.:-(

Comment: What security issues are you converned with ? Never seen one. Have you read the stuff i've written ? you need to install some packages via winetricks to make it work properly. Direct installing it over wine won't work okay.

Comment: I seen a document about some spams or worms or viruses can run trough wine!

Comment: Well unless you play online poker or some cracked warez stuff through wine with ie or some other stuff, you are %99.9 safe.

Answer (score 0):

gedit is great, you can add a class browser and zen coding.

Comment: @IVIR3zaM - google for gmate, some gedit plugins pack, makes it almost perfect (amd makes it look like textmate, too!)